# 'SARIMAXResults' object has no attribute '_params_ma

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, state-space

I am trying to creat a Seasonal ARIMA model by using the class `statsmodels.statespace.sarimax.SARIMA`, and the model seems to be well created.
[image: The JPEG of SARIMA Model summary]

Now, I want to pass the AR coefficents and MA coefficents to variables seperately, but it appear a error that: `SARIMAXResults` object has no attribute `_params_ma`.
[image: The JPEG of error]

What should I do to correct the error?

Comment: I have a new problem now. After the model is fitted, I tried to use `SARIMAXResults.cov_params` to get the correlation matrix of parameter estimates, but on jupyter notebook, it only shows me `<bound method LikelihoodModelResults.cov_params of <statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResultsWrapper object at 0x000002252A63C278>>`, it seems the process suceed to a calculate a matrix as a result, but why it can't be shown?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly, I find it was my own fault.

Following my SARIMA(2,0,0)X(0,0,1,12) model, the non-seasonal element has orders(p,d,q)=(2,0,0), and the seasonal element has orders (P,D,Q,s)=(0,0,1,12). Thus, the model says that the data has a nonseasonal AR(2) pattern, and a seasonal MA(1)_12 pattern. 
As a result, the coefficient of nonseasonal MA pattern which is corresponding to `SARIMAXResults.maparams` will not be estimated. By contrast, the coefficient of seasonal MA partter which is corresponding to `SARIMAXResults.seasonalmaparams` will be estimated.

For purpose of getting estimated coefficient value of seasonal MA pattern, I should call `seasonalmaparams()` method, instead of `maparams()`.

The error problem is solved now. :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, after seeing the soure code, the other propblem added in the comment is also solved.

Actually, the parenthesis should be added to call the attribute of `SARIMAXResults`, so `cov_params()` will show the covariance-variance matrix, as following:
[cov_params matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/868xt.png)

Next, for sake of calculating the correlation matrix of parameters, I coded as following:

```
# Step1: Pass the covariance-variance matrix to a specified DataFrame
df_cov = final_result.cov_params()
# Step2: Creat a blank DataFrame which will be used to store correlation values
coef_name = [r'$b_1$',r'$b_2$',r'$\theta_1$',r'$\phi_{12}$',r'$\phi_{24}$']
cor_df = pd.DataFrame(index=coef_name,columns=coef_name)
cor_df.loc[:,:]=''
# Step3: Loop the covariance-variance matrix and calculate the correlation
var=[0]*5
for i in range(5):
    var[i] = df_cov.iloc[i,i]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if j<=i:
            corvar = df_cov.iloc[i,j] 
            cor = corvar/np.sqrt(var[i]*var[j])
            cor_df.iloc[i,j] = round(cor,2)
        else:
            continue
# Step4: Show the correlation matrix(as type of DataFrame)
cor_df
```

Finally, the correlaton matrix is well calculated as shown as below:
[correlation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUepP.png)

Thanks for your attention, no more question now.